# How to use take() in RxJS without unsubscribing to observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have an observable representing an infinite data source and I want users to fetch pages of `n` items interactively (e.g. clicking `next` or using infinite scroll).

The problem is that when I use `take()`, it also unsubscribes to my source, so when I want to take more items, it starts all over again. I'm aware of `skip()` so I could fast forward, but since my `source` makes api calls, it might get expensive to do that (it uses `Observable.defer` under the hood to fetch pages when necessary).

I've also read about [pausable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pausable.md), but it seems to me quite dirty (would need to disable the pause when we need more data, then count items and enable again after N items, I think).

```
let source = someFunction(); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...]

// On page load
source.take(3).subscribe(item => render(item)); // [1,2,3]

// When user clicks "next page"
source.take(3).subscribe(item => render(item)); // [1,2,3], expected [4,5,6]
```

How can I keep my subscription open, while taking a few items at the time?

FWIW, I'm using RxJs 5.5.2 with Angular 5.0.0

Answer (score 1):

`take` is operator intend to terminate source. You may would like to peek operator like `bufferCount` or `windowCount` to create inner observables contains specific number of element you'd like to have, handle each inner observable as you want (and merge it back if necessary).